# Apply CSS class on URL hash change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have recently started working in jquery. It should be simple but i couldn't find solution so far. I'm trying to navigate the slide using URL hash tag. I'm able to work through the click event but when I try to manually change the tag in URL, it fails. Its a content slider inside the header and footer.

What i want is the click function to work when the URL hash change and goto particular slide.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var currentPage,
  pointer,
  slideMargin,
  contentPointer=1,
  sildeNum = $('.page').length,
  wrapperWidth = 100 * sildeNum,
  slideWidth = 100 / sildeNum;
 
 $(".wrapper").css({
     width: wrapperWidth + '%'
 });
 
 $(".page").css({
     width: slideWidth + '%'
 });
 

  $(".page-wrapper li").css("left", '100%');
  $(".page-wrapper li:nth-child("+contentPointer+")").css("left", '0%');

 
 $("a.scrollitem").click(function(){
  pointer=this.id;
  contentPointer=Number(pointer) + 1;
    

  $(".page-wrapper li").css("left", '100%');
  $(".page-wrapper li:nth-child("+contentPointer+")").css("left", '0%');
  
    $("a.scrollitem").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  $(".page").removeClass("selected");
  $(".page-wrapper li:nth-child("+contentPointer+")").addClass("selected");
    return true;
 }); 

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #263729;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: block; }

  .wrapper nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 33.3%; }

    .wrapper nav a {
      color: #FFFFFF; }

  .wrapper ul {
    height: 40%; }

    .wrapper ul li {
      position: absolute;
      background: #992213;
      min-height: 40%;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
      float: left; }


#p1 {
  background: #0C717A; }

#p2 {
  background: #009900; }

#p3 {
  background: #0000FF; }

a {
  color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
     <nav>
        <a id="0"  href="#p1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>
         <a id="1" href="#p2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
         <a id="2" href="#p3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>
    </nav>
    <ul class="page-wrapper">
        <li id="p1" class="page selected">
            <h1>Content slide 1</h1>
        </li>
        
        <li id="p2" class="page">
            <h1>Content slide 2</h1>
        </li>
        
        <li id="p3" class="page">
            <h1>Content slide 3</h1>
        </li
    ></ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The hash tag now triggers! But I want to slide the each div from right to left like a slider! When ever it's active! Another things is that my main page has a hidden menu on top which also hash #mainmenu. The slider is in #body! How do I activate the right slider like eg: www.example.com#body/#p3???

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are already adding a new class `selected` to your link when it's active like below.

```
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

So you just need to style your links when they have this `selected` class.

```
/* find all selected links inside wrapper
   .wrapper is required to add specifity
   .wrapper .selected > .wrapper nav a
*/
.wrapper .selected{
  color : red;
}

/* setting some default styles for headings so that
   they won't inherit wrapper styles */
h1 {
  color : #fff;
}
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGEbjP) showcasing the above changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The hash tag now triggers! But I want to slide the each div from right to left like a slider! When ever it's active! Another things is that my main page has a hidden menu on top which also hash #mainmenu. The slider is in #body! How do I activate the right slider like eg: www.example.com#body/#p3???

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp) there is widespread support for the `onhashchange` event.

This means it is safe to replace your `$("a.scrollitem").click(function(){...}` with this:-

```
$(document).on('hashchange', function() {
    pointer = 1*location.hash.substr(2) // remove leading '#p'

    $(".page-wrapper li")
    .css("left", '100%')
    .removeClass("selected")
    .eq(pointer)
    .css("left", '0%')
    .addClass("selected")

    $("a.scrollitem")
    .removeClass("selected")
    .eq(pointer)
    .addClass("selected")
})

if (location.hash.length)
    $(document).trigger('hashchange')
```

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the $("a.scrollitem").click(function() function with yours but the problem still the same. The navigation links works properly by clicking on it. But whenever i manually changed the URL Hash tag it goes the specific ID but the class related to that ID doesnt  trigger.

For example http://example/page-temp-slides.html#p1 when manually changed to  http://example/page-temp-slides.html#p2 jumps to the ID which has class .css("left", '100%') and its offscreen. The selected id should be assigned .css("left", '0%') which should he displayed active

Comment: When the user edits the hash portion of the URL some browsers reload the entire page instead of just firing the `onhashchange` event. I have edited my answer to take this into account and now it triggers that event on page load (if there is a hash portion in the URL).